# How to check a button is clicked or not from a other activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two `Activity`s A and B. `Activity B` have `Button OK` I want to check wheather  the `Button Ok` is clicked or not from `Activity A`

Comment: you can use public static boolean flag by clicking this flag was true and after cheching from A Activity set to false

Comment: i don't understand this question well. because when you're in ActivityB your ActivityA is paused (or removed) - depending on activity lifecycle. but if you need check if user clicked that button you may send this information within Bundle (setExtra) on launching intent [basically from A to B]

Comment: if you down voting please provide comments.

Comment: Even if the question itself is not clear.. why everybody writing answer with presumptions, I applause for your enthusiastic support but I guess all need to help Abhijit by making him write clear question first.

Comment: @all Please read the question carefully..!! I think you will get what Abhijit try to say after 2 or 3 time carefull reading..

Comment: @MKJPrakash where you finding difficulty to understand my question.please confirm i will make it clear.

Comment: What is the usability of this? Explain where you use this?

Comment: @Sino raj i have a viewpager in which other activity's were attached there in a scenario i need it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set boolean variable inside the `Button ok`

Comment: I think here you will find all whay you need: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

Answer (score 1):

When you  click on `Button Ok` in `Activity B` you need to save `bollean btnOkClicked = true`. 
 And from `Activity A` just read this value. You can save it - what ever you want (`public static` or in [shared preference](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html))
 Hope it's help

Answer (score 0):

You can make One `Interface` class and Create One `Boolean Method` with specific `Name`
initialize that Interface Class Object in `Activity B` and assign `Boolean Method` in `Button Ok` click and implement `interface` in `Activity A`

Answer (score 0):

You have a design issue on your app (that is probably the reason people is downvoting)

If `Button Ok` is inside `Activity B`, and `Button Ok` is clicked, that means that `Activity A` is not currently active (paused or destroyed).

What you probably want to do is to start activity B for result using => https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent, int)

and in activity A override the activity result with this using => https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int, int, android.content.Intent)

the following tutorial explains nicely about activity results:
http://www.mybringback.com/tutorial-series/12186/android-startactivityforresult-example/

Answer (score -1):

Create a static class in with a boolean flag. then set the flag from the activity B when the button OK is pressed, then check the flag from your activity A.

/*This is the store class ..*/

```
public class Store {

/*
 * Singleton

 */
    private boolean flag
private static Store instance;


public static synchronized Store getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new Store();
    } 
    return instance;
}
    public String getFlag() {
    return flag;
}
public void setFlag(boolean flag) {
    this.flag= flag;
}
```

// This is the implementation in your Activity B

//onButton Click set this flag

Store.getInstance().setFlag(true);

....

//This is the implementation in Activity A

if(Store.getInstance().getFlag()){

** The button is clicked

}else
** The button is not clicked..